# Gradle version catalogs for plugins with group

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to figure out whether it is possible to declare plugin in version catalogs if it has a group also.

If i try to declare it like this

```
libs.versions.toml

[plugins]
google-services = { id = "com.google.gms:google-services", version = "4.3.10" }

build.gradle
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.google.services)
}
```

I receive the next error

```
> plugin id 'com.google.gms:google-services' is invalid: Plugin id contains invalid char ':' (only ASCII alphanumeric characters, '.', '_' and '-' characters are valid)
```

Any suggestions how to use it properly for plugins?

Answer (score 6):

With the help of the gradle community in telegram i've found the solution

In the `settings.gradle.kts` need to declare such section

```
pluginManagement {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.id.startsWith("com.google.gms.google-services")) {
                useModule("com.google.gms:google-services:${requested.version}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the `libs.version.toml` file declare it like this

```
[plugins]
google-services = { id = "com.google.gms.google-services", version = "4.3.10" }
```

In the `build.gradle` apply it like this

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.google.services)
}
```